# Ubuntu 20.04 access to NAS files

Tags: networking, nautilus, files, samba

After upgrade to 20.04 Files (and Krusader!) can find the volumes on local NAS, but individual files and folders are returned as "No such file or folder; has it been deleted?".

Taking note of previous related posts I have tried:

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

add:

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP    
client min protocol = NT1    
server max protocol = NT1    
client min protocol = CORE
```

Not sure what else to try. The 18.04 box still works perfectly and I can't work out if it is a Nautilus, Gnome, Samba, or (unlikely) a kernel thing.
Stumped! Can anyone help?

Comment: It almost sounds like a variation of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1872476 There is a PPA referenced in that bug report with a fix here if you are interested: https://launchpad.net/~sergiodj/+archive/ubuntu/samba-bug1872476-v2 Another option is a cifs mount. If you are new to a cifs mount I can give you an example.

Answer (score 1):

file-as-folder is fixed via https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1872476

It's fixed in the package https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.2 which is currently sitting in focal-proposed, and will be in updates shortly.

Answer (score -2):

I make a copy of the file `smb.conf`

```
cd /etc/samba
sudo cp smb.conf smb.conf.old
```

then I changed the original file

```
sudo gedit smb.conf
```

In global section under work group I add a new line

```
#This new line is to obtain access to my DNS-320l   
client min protocol = NT1
```

I save the file and finally re-start my computer and everything worked, I can access my files. Of course I put my credentials, user and password of my DNS, I hope this could be useful for someone else.

Comment: OP already has `client min protocol = NT1`